# Creating a custom pcore for Xilinx ISE 14.7?

Tags: xilinx, xilinx-ise, xilinx-edk

A bit of a general question, but what is the most popular/common/easiest way of creating a custom pcore?

I have seen some examples and they were mostly done on Matlab and since I do not have Matlab anywhere, I am a bit lost here. There has got to be a proper way of doing without it!

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it with VHDL or Verilog languages, but after that you need to make few files like `.mdp` and `.pao`, create directory move all the files there and then put the directory to a library.

Detailed information you can find in [Xilinx Manual](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_4/psf_rm.pdf)